# How do I install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, partial-upgrade

I am a senior and I only use Ubuntu on an older computer that had Vista. It's just occasional use and when I got a message asking if I wanted to upgrade, I should have said NO.  It was upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 and stopped.  After a few hours, I just turned it off.  Now it will only open to a list on the left hand side of the screen.  I downloaded 16.04 onto a USB drive but I can't understand how to get it to accept it.

Please do not tell me anything complicated as I will not understand it.  I just want it to download 16.04 via the USB.  Thank you.

Comment: Generally you'd want to look for something in your system BIOS to have it boot from the USB drive instead of the HDD. Do the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick not answer your questions?

Comment: You're telling something about a list on left hand side of the screen. Can you add an image/photo/screenshot with it?

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer? You cannot simply download the Ubuntu file to the USB. You download it to your hard disk and then "burn it" to the USB similar to how you would burn a CD or DVD only using a different program. In either case it is the same Ubuntu file name with a .iso file extension.

Comment: About 3 years ago I "simply" downloaded ubuntu to a usb and put it on my netbook and it still works perfectly.  Last year, I "simply" downloaded ubuntu to a usb and replaced vista on another computer and it worked perfectly until today, when stupidly, I chose to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 which stopped installing at some point.  Hours later, I turned it off.  I put 16.04 on a usb, I burned it to a dvd.  The computer will not boot to either one.  It asks me for a login and I put ubuntu.  It asks for a password and does not accept one.  How do I make it boot from the DVD or USB?